# How can I check a LinkedList for several values after eachother?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I want to make an application which allocates seats in a cinema in a simple way.

I have a LinkedList which is randomly filled with 0 'seat is available' or 1 'seat is taken'. This LinkedList is generated by the variable int 'seatsTotal', the LinkedList is then filled with the Math.random function with 1 or 0.

The idea is that the user gives a variable which is how many seats they would like to book, after that, a (perhaps recursive) method will look for (example) 5 seats which are labeled with 0 (available).

If there are no 5 seats available after (next to) eachother, the method has to look for 4 available seats and 1 seat seperate. If there are no 4 seats available, the application will look for 3 seats and 2 seats etc.

My first question is; I know I can use LinkedList.contains() to check if a certain value is present, but how can I check if (for example) 0 is presents 5 times in a row?

My second question is; How can I handle the method if there are no 5 seats available and I will have to look for 4 seats and 1 seat (for instance)?

I'm really stuck with this, help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main {

    static int seatCount = 10;
    int verzoekAantal = 3;
    int consecutiveLength = 0; // Consecutive free seats length
    int index = 0;
    int startIndex = -1; // Store the start of consecutive free seats
    LinkedList<Seat> consecutiveList = new LinkedList<>(); // Store startIndex -> length

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fillList(seatCount).toArray()));
        System.out.println(fillSeats(3).toString());
    }

    //Deze methode geeft via de Math package een willekeurig getal, 1 (bezet) of 0 (vrij)
    static int giveRandomAvailability() {
        return intValue(Math.random() * 2);
    }


    //Deze methode creëert een LinkedList van grootte 'seatCount' en vult de plaatsen een voor een met 0 of 1 op willekeur
    static LinkedList fillList(int seats){
        LinkedList<Seat> list = new LinkedList<Seat>();
        seats = seatCount;

        for(int i = 0; i < seats; i++){
            Seat seat = new Seat();
            seat.availability = giveRandomAvailability();
            seat.seatNumber = (i + 1);
            list.add(seat);
        }

        return list;
    }

    static Map fillSeats(int n){
        LinkedList<Seat> newList = fillList(seatCount);
        int consecutiveLength = 0; // Consecutive free seats length
        int index = 0;
        int startIndex = -1; // Store the start of consecutive free seats
        int remConsecutiveLength = 0;
        System.out.println(newList.toString());
        Map<Integer, Integer> consecutiveMap = new HashMap<>(); // Store startIndex -> length

        for (Seat seat : newList) {
            if (seat.IsFree()) {
                if (startIndex < 0) {
                    startIndex = index;
                }
                consecutiveLength ++;
            } else {
                consecutiveMap.put(startIndex + 1, consecutiveLength);
                if (consecutiveLength >= n) {
                    System.out.println("SEATS FOUND, " + n + " seats available counting from " + (seat.seatNumber - n));
                }

//                if(consecutiveLength > remConsecutiveLength) {
//                    remConsecutiveLength = consecutiveLength;
//                }
                startIndex = -1;
                consecutiveLength = 0;
            }
            index++;
        }
        if (startIndex >= 0) {
            consecutiveMap.put(startIndex + 1, consecutiveLength);
        }
//                    if (remConsecutiveLength < n) {
//                    while(n > 1) {
//                        System.out.println("Looking for seats which are not next to eachother");
//                        n--;
//                        fillSeats(n);
//                    }
//                }
        Map<Integer, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(consecutiveMap);
        return treeMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the first part of your question, you may iterate the linked list.  For the second part, this is much more complex, and I'm sure a lot of work has gone into developing seating algorithms which give the best experience.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you Tim. Yes, there are undoubtedly a lot of great algorithms for this, mine can remain simple though.

Comment: create a method and pass the greatest number of seats you want next to each other, and then have your method return those seats in a list. if the method can't find five, it would return whatever the next greatest number it did find as it traversed the list

Comment: How are you handling rows with a simple `LinkedList`? Any given space is not a single row, infinitely wide (even theater in the round). So finding _N_ consecutive 0s isn't really indicative of much unless you know they are in the same row. Then when you want to find some subdivision, the preference will be for seats located closely together spatially over just random seats.

Comment: @KevinO I'm pretty sure you can write conditional logic to check that you're counting seats in the same row.

Comment: **I'm really stuck with this** could you provide some code with what you've done so far

Comment: @Aquaballin, well yes one could. But as the specific way the system is modeled directly impacts any algorithmic solution, and lacking any indication that the LinkedList actually has such data, it seems like it is an modification to the base question of counting consecutive _N_ 0s, non? It is not just _N_ 0s, but _N_ 0s that meet additional criteria. Furthermore, the question states that the `LinkedList` is filled with values of 0 or 1, which will imply it is not modeling a `Seat`, but an integer. Which is why @oreh asked for code.

Comment: @KevinO There are no rows, just seats, increasing in number.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question :

If you want to find n consecutive empty seats, you have to loop through your LinkedList and count free seats until you found n consecutive, or you go through all seats.

```
public List<Seat> findNConsecutiveEmptySeats(List<Seat> seats, int n) {
    List<Seat> freeSeats = new LinkedList<Seat>();
    for(Seat s : seats) {
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
            freeSeats.add(s);
        } else {
            freeSeats.clear();
        }
        if(freeSeats.size() >= n) {
            break;
        }
     }
     if(freeSeats.size() < n) {
        freeSeats.clear();
     }
     return freeSeats;
}
```

---

To answer the second part of your question, You need to call the previous method with n=5. If the list returned contains 5 seats, great you found them, return it. If it contains an empty list, call the method with n=4 then n=1. Etc...

```
public List<Seat> findNEmptySeats(List<Seat> seats, int n) {
    List<Seats> freeSeats = findNConsecutiveEmptySeats(seats, n);
    if(freeSeats.size() == n) {
        return freeSeats;
    }
    freeSeats = findConsecutiveEMptySeats(seats, n-1);
    freeSeats.addAll(findConsecutiveEMptySeats(seats, 1));
    if(freeSeats.size() == n) {
        return freeSeats;
    }
    freeSeats = findConsecutiveEMptySeats(seats, n-2);
    freeSeats.addAll(findConsecutiveEMptySeats(seats, 2));
    if(freeSeats.size() == n) {
        return freeSeats;
    }

    ...

}
```

***Note :*** this code is not complete, for example after looking for n-1 seats, you need to remove the found seats before looking for the 1 seat, otherwise you could return an already found seat.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this approach and let you know if it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the consecutive seats and store those items.

Assume that you're store your seat information in a `Seat` class, and we have `List<Seat> seats` as input. and `n` is number of seats you want to find.

```
int consecutiveLength = 0; // Consecutive free seats length
int index = 0;
int startIndex = -1; // Store the start of consecutive free seats
Map<Integer, Integer> consecutiveMap = new HashMap<>(); // Store startIndex -> length

for (Seat seat : seats) {
  if (seat.isFree()) {
    if (startIndex < 0) {
      startIndex = index;
    }
    consecutiveLength ++;
  } else {
    consecutiveMap.put(startIndex, consecutiveLength);
    if (consecutiveLength == n) {
      // Found, do something here
    }
    // Reset
    startIndex = -1;
    consecutiveLength = 0;
  }
  index++;
}
```

After this you have access to all of `consecutiveLength` in `consecutiveMap`.

You can also return immediately by test `consecutiveLength == n` in above `else` block.

By accessing every number of `consecutiveLength` you are able to choose the sub option (4 consecutive + 1 single, etc)

**Edit**

After running the code your `consecutiveMap` will look like

```
{1 -> 1, 3 -> 4, 8 ->1, ...}
```

It reads: At index 1, there's 1 consecutive Seat.

At index 3, there's a 4 consecutive seats block.
....

You access the consecutive length in your list by `consecutiveMap.values()`

It will give you `{1, 4, 1, 2, ...}`.

And your problem is reduced to: Pick several item in an array so that sum of them are `n`. You can even sort them to pick from larger to smaller consecutive length.

It's pretty straightforward.

You can bruteforce here also, since number of seat per row is not very large.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I am looking for. It seems to find available seats very well. However, I do not understand how I can handle non-consecutive seat bookings (for example 4 + 1) with this code. Could you please explain this?

Comment: And am I right to assume that n is the wanted amount of seats in a booking here?

Comment: That cleared up a lot, thank you, I will definitely give this a try.

Comment: Your code works well but I still do not know how I can 'retry' the method if n = 5 and there are no 5 consecutive available seats. Could you help me with this? I will edit my question so you can see my code.